# How to use cacheSweave in a batch Sweave call via make?

Tags: r, sweave

I've been using a makefile to automate the running of Sweave for my analysis reports in R using the approach outlined by [Jeromy Anglim](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/11/sweave-tutorial-using-sweave-r-and-make.html) with great success.  I recently heard about the cacheSweave package and I would like to incorporate that functionality into my Rnw file. I use the ProjectTemplate package to load all of the necessary files at startup, and that takes some time because I have to preprocess the raw data files.  The examples in the cacheSweave vignette show how to run Sweave with the cacheSweave driver within an R session:

```
library(cacheSweave)
Sweave("foo.Rnw", driver = cacheSweaveDriver)
```

How would I use the cacheSweaveDriver in my command to run Sweave in batch mode?  In my makefile this is how I invoke Sweave:

```
$(TEXFILE).tex: $(TEXFILE).Rnw
        R CMD SWeave $(TEXFILE).Rnw
        R CMD Stangle $(TEXFILE).Rnw
```

I am using Emacs+ESS to create the .Rnw file and run make.  Here is the rest of my makefile for reference:

```
TEXFILE=report_presentation
PLOTDIR= ../graphs
PLOTS=
FIGURES= $(PLOTDIR)/$(PLOTS)
INPUTS=

all: $(TEXFILE).pdf; make clean

.PHONY: all clean

 $(TEXFILE).pdf: $(TEXFILE).tex $(FIGURES) $(INPUTS)
# Initial run
pdflatex $(TEXFILE)

# Run bibtex if missing citations
@if(grep "Citation" $(TEXFILE).log > /dev/null);\
then \
    bibtex $(TEXFILE);\
    pdflatex $(TEXFILE); \
fi

# Recompile if instructed
@if(grep "Rerun" $(TEXFILE).log > /dev/null);\
then \
    pdflatex $(TEXFILE); \
fi

    $(TEXFILE).tex: $(TEXFILE).Rnw
        R CMD Sweave $(TEXFILE).Rnw
        R CMD Stangle $(TEXFILE).Rnw

    ## Remove unnecessary files
    clean:
       -rm -f $(TEXFILE).log $(TEXFILE).aux $(TEXFILE).out $(TEXFILE).blg $(TEXFILE).bbl $(TEXFILE).nav $(TEXFILE).snm $(TEXFILE).toc Rplots.pdf
```

Answer (score 3):

Gregor Gorjanc has a shell script to allow this:

http://ggorjan.blogspot.com/2008/11/sweavesh-plays-with-cachesweave.html

It is more elegant than my homemade solution: which is to make a simple file called "runcachesweave.R" containing:

```
library(cacheSweave)
Sweave("foo.Rnw", driver = cacheSweaveDriver)
```

And then calling R CMD BATCH runcachesweave.R;latexmk -pdf foo.tex